# question on displaying UIProgressView in each table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to upload a few files to a server. The files are listed on the `UItableview`. My question is:

What should i do to display `UIProgressView` in each table cell and show the progress of each file being uploaded.

My current code is able to show the UIProgressView in each cell but when i try to upload, the progress bar did not move. The program is suppose to upload 1 file at a time which after the first file is completed, the second will start to upload. In response, when the first file is done, the progress bar of the first file will stop and the progress bar for the secong file will start to move. Hope this is clear. I really need some help on this and i can't find it on the web.Thanks in advance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to maintain the progress value of each cell in an array.

I guess you must be setting the progress value of UIProgressView object at cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so you need to call [self.tableView reloadData] whenever you get callback from you network code which is uploading file to server with current upload size...

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (could be optimized): (Sorry for the formatting, could not get it working)

- Create UIProgressView for each cell in your tableView
- Create a field in your view controller, where you will store number of bytes already uploaded (bytesAlreadyUploaded) - you should repeatidly receive such info from your uploader.
- Create a field where you will store number of bytes to be uploaded for the current upload (bytesToUpload)
- Create a field where you will assign pointer to the progress view currently used (progressViewCurrentlyUsed)
- Create a method in which you will refresh your progress:

> - (void) refreshProgress {
>           progressViewCurrentlyUsed.progress =
>     bytesAlreadyUploaded /
>     (CGFloat)bytesToUpload;
>     }

- Create a NSTimer, which will call this refreshProgress method several times a second:

> refreshTimer = [NSTimer
>   timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
>   selector:@selector(refreshProgress)
>   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
>     [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
>   addTimer:refreshTimer
>   forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- When you change the file being uploaded, change progressViewCurrentlyUsed, bytesToUpload and zero bytesAlreadyUploaded

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I understand the first few point but got lost along the way. Could you elaborate more? Thanks Thanks

Comment: I do not know what class or something (call it UPLOADER) you use to upload your files to server, but I assume, that you must have some feedback from UPLOADER about upload process. This feedback can be for example calling a delegate methods which you implement in YOUR class. I.e. : when some chunk of data is uploaded to server the UPLOADER will call some method in YOUR class, e.g. - (void) dataChunkUploaded:(NSUInteger)length. The same when upload of some file finishes: the UPLOADER may call - (void) fileDidUpload:(NSString *)filename. In these methods you must do the things I described.

Comment: Thanks, that sure clear some doubt. can you explain more on creating a field where i can assign pointer to the progress view currently used. Thanks Thanks.

Comment: In your .h file in interface declaration of your class, create a field in such a way:
UIProgressView *progressViewCurrentlyUsed;